# Return specific column through select in Linq To SQL

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

I have below code that returns all the columns in student. 
But I want to return only one column. Any solution?

```
 IEnumerable<DataRow> x = from student in dt.AsEnumerable()
                                     join d in dt1.AsEnumerable() on student.Field<string>("Name") equals d.Field<string>("LapName")
                                     where d.Field<string>("LapName") == "HP"
                                     select student;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the column(s) you require in the `select`, in your case, something like this:

```
IEnumerable<string> x = from student in dt.AsEnumerable()
                        join d in dt1.AsEnumerable() on student.Field<string>("Name") equals d.Field<string>("LapName")
                        where d.Field<string>("LapName") == "HP"
                        select student.Field<string>("Name");
```

Note that the return type for `x` is now `IEnumerable` of `string` instead of `DataRow`.